# Cannot find sbt launcher 0.11.2

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.0

I have a `Play 2.0` app that uses `sbt 0.11.2`. However when I set up a new `Play` server, it grabbed the latest version of `sbt 0.11.3`. Now when I run `sbt compile` on the new server, it complains

```
Detected sbt version 0.11.2
Cannot find sbt launcher 0.11.2
Please download: 
/sbt-launch.jartypesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-launch/0.11.2
/sbt-launch.jarc2-user/.sbt/.lib/0.11.2
```

I tried downloading `sbt-launch 0.11.2` and putting in the same folder as `sbt` but still get the same error. Incidentally, is there a difference between `play compile` vs. `sbt compile` because `play compile` works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes I think there is a difference between `play compile` and `sbt compile`, if your `sbt` script uses a different SBT version, in your case vertion 0.11.2 rather than Play's 0.11.3.

Perhaps you should start using SBT 0.11.3 instead?

I just upgraded to Play 2.1-SNAPSHOT (Git rev. f7de038a48, Fri May 25) which uses SBT 0.11.3, and I had to make this change in `project/build.properties`:

Change from: `sbt.version=0.11.2`
to: `sbt.version=0.11.3`

And I linked my SBT bash script to the one included with Play, i.e. 0.11.3 not 0.11.2.

Comment: Any idea what the differences are? I have considered switching to 0.11.3 but unfortunately this is a multi-developer project each with his own machine setup plus it wouldn't solve the problem for the next sbt upgrade, we need to freeze the version.

Comment: No I don't.  Actually, I attempted to start SBT 0.11.2 in my project dir, but it ditn't even start, because it couldn't find the Play SBT plugin. Although I attempted to add Play's local Ivy/Maven repository to `pugins.sbt`.

Comment: But if you've created a new Play project, then you'd use Play SBT Plugin version 0.11.3. However when you start SBT 0.11.2, won't SBT be looking for Play SBT Plugin version 0.11.2, which doesn't exist in Play's local Ivy repository? the JAR that Play has build, would be found in a path that contains "0.11.3" not "0.11.2"? (When I start SBT, it seems to include the SBT version in the file path to the Play SBT plugin.)

Comment: I didn't create a new Play project, I just set up a new Play server and cloned an existing Play project that uses sbt 0.11.2.

Answer (score 1):

If you're compiling Play20 from source, after running the `./build` command in `./Play20/framework`, you'll be in the Play shell.

Run the command `about` and you can check what version of sbt is being run.

```
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.12.0
[info] The current project is {file:/home/jw/code/Play20/framework/}Root
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.9.2
[info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.tools.mima.plugin.MimaPlugin,        com.typesafe.sbtscalariform.ScalariformPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.2
```

Then in your project directory, change the `./project/build.properties` to the correct version.