# Cannot install new 0.11.3 sbt on Ubuntu 10.04LTS

Tags: scala, sbt, ubuntu-10.04

This process used to work fine in 0.11.2 but the recent change w.r.t to sbt group ID changed to org.scala-sbt (from org.scala-tools.sbt) seems to have broken a dependency.

I've got a 10.04 LTS machine to which I added the Typesafe deb repository using the deb package file, described in: https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Setup.

When I try to install from the repo I get:

```
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES ::
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: org.scala-tools.sbt#scripted-plugin_2.9.1;0.11.3: not found
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

[warn] module not found: org.scala-tools.sbt#scripted-plugin_2.9.1;0.11.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/scripted-plugin_2.9.1/0.11.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn] /home/jasonmaclulich/.ivy2/local/org.scala-tools.sbt/scripted-plugin_2.9.1/0.11.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repo: tried
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/scripted- plugin_2.9.1/0.11.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn] http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/sbt/scripted-plugin_2.9.1/0.11.3/scripted-plugin_2.9.1-0.11.3.pom
```

How do I instruct sbt to look for scripted-plugin at the right group id?

I also tried a manual install with this launcher (following the UNIX install instructions):

//typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.11.3-2/sbt-launch.jar

And I still get the following unresolved dependency:

```
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES ::
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] :: org.scala-tools.sbt#scripted-plugin_2.9.1;0.11.3: not found
[warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Thoughts?

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: See my answer here as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760345/cannot-find-sbt-launcher-0-11-2/12224226#12224226

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd update this with how I got around it, if I explicitly set the version of sbt to 0.11.2 in my project/build.properties file, i.e., `sbt.version=0.11.2`.

```
Detected sbt version 0.11.2
Cannot find sbt launcher 0.11.2
Please download: 
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-tools.sbt/sbt-launch/0.11.2/sbt-launch.jar
     To  /home/<username>/.sbt/.lib/0.11.2/sbt-launch.jar
```

I then installed the required files and I was able to continue compiling like I was used to.

While it isn't a direct solution it does let me continue with work.

Comment: Were you able to run it compile it successfully after switching back to version 0.11.3? I am facing a similar issue but with a different library

Comment: Yes, luckily, my project was setup around 0.11.2 and forcing the compilation to 0.11.2 just restored it to a previously working state. I take it you meant after I switched back to 0.11.2.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed latest SBT on Ubuntu successfully, but indirectly, by installing Typesafe Stack.

Comment: Are you talking about ubuntu 10.04 LTS ?

Comment: Thanks, did you use the instructions here to do this? [link](http://typesafe.com/stack/download) under the Ubuntu/Debian section?

Answer (score 0):

By now, sbt-0.11.3-build-0100 is available (http://apt.typesafe.com/pool/pool/main/s/sbt/), so you should be able to simply upgrade to solve your problem. If that doesn't work or if you're curious about the original problem, here's my diagnosis.

As you tried to do, you do need to use a new launcher for SBT 0.11.3 to use the new group ID, `org.scala-sbt`. Your second error message still shows a failure which refers to `org.scala-tools.sbt` - that's bad, and suggests you're in fact still using the old launcher.

Could you make sure that when you're launching `sbt`, you're launching the script you created and not the one from the Debian package? Please try using the full path for launching sbt, for instance `~/bin/sbt`.

If that helps, you should fix the PATH so that `~/bin` (or wherever you installed your script) comes before the directory where the system SBT is installed, which (I would say, but it's a matter of opinion) is generally useful.